# NetBeans doesn't recognise JDK

Tags: java, netbeans

I am new to using NetBeans (got it this afternoon), and it won't let me build my project.

I wrote some code, and the first line (`package io.github.kettle3d.Launcher;`) has an error saying the following:

```
cannot access java.lang
 Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
```

I'm using NetBeans version 12, with OpenJDK 12 (I don't have a Java account and honestly don't want Oracle getting all my personal info), both of them I installed today.
I have no idea what's going on. Could someone please give me a pointer?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found out the issue was because NetBeans's JDK search path was set to /usr for some reason, but I changed it to where I installed JDK. The config file was (in my case, it'll be different depending on where you installed NetBeans) in /home/kettle/Beans of Net/netbeans/etc/netbeans.conf.

Comment: Why don't you just put JDK on the classpath the way the installation instructions suggest? That way, you can use Java from the console. You don't always want to be firing up a full blown IDE for every little thing.

Comment: I downloaded the tarball for JDK and didn't see an option to install it to /usr, so all the files are sitting where I extracted them.